# Access outer variable inside a block and Y-combinator

Tags: lambda-calculus, y-combinator, xbase

I hope you all to be fine. I'm implementing the fixed-point **Y-combinator** in Harbour and I'm having some troubles with it. Well, the Y-combinator can be defined by the *lambda-calculus* as:

`Y = (λh.λF.F(λ x.((h(h))(F))(x))) (λh.λF.F(λ x.((h(h))(F))(x)))`

I'm trying to apply memoization with Y-combinator by performance questions. My current implementation is:

```
Function YMem( bF, aCache )
   Local xAnswer
    If !lCache ; lCache := { } ; EndIf
    Return { |Arg| Iif( aCache[ Arg ] ;
        , /* then      */ aCache[ Arg ];
        , /* otherwise */ aCache[ Arg ] := ;
            Eval( Eval( bF, { |N| Eval( Eval( YMem, bF, aCache ), N ) } ), Arg ) ) }
```

Basically, I can't use statements inside blocks, but I can use expressions and it works just fine. I'm avoiding an infinite recursion and the limit going through by 0 to infinite.

Until this time, it compiles just fine, but when I'm trying to access a variable of an outer block, Harbour kicks me in Face!

To test the Y-combinator implementation, I try to apply a simple implemetation of fibonacci sequence, but when I return a block that receives a parameter `G` and implicitly returns a block that receives a parameter `N`, `G` becames unavailable for me and the compiler says me that "Outer codeblock variable is out of reach".

```
Function Main
    Local bFib := YMem( { |G| ;
        { |N| ;
            Iif( N == 0, 1, Iif( N == 1, 1, Eval( G, N - 1 ) + Eval( G, N - 2) ) );
        } ;
    } )
    Return
```

This would also allow me to curry blocks. My question is: how can I access an outer variable inside a block, in Harbour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Harbour, Clipper and xBase-based programming languages, blocks *never* can refer
to the variable of the parent block. Blocks are not closures. We can reach that by
creating local storages and using them in the internal blocks:

```
Function TestOuterScope
  Local accA
  Local bAdd := { |A| accA := A, { |B| accA + B } }
  Return Eval( Eval( bAdd, 10 ), 20 )
```